# Date conversion on Live Server issue

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, parsing, datetime

I have a web application that when working in development is fine, but going to Live it does not work.

What the situation is to do with dates. A user enters in a date in the UK format through a text, and I use DateTime.ParseExact(txtDate.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", Nothing) to tell the date datatype that the date must remain in UK style. As I say, everything is fine in development, but when it goes to Live, it says the that the string is not a valid datetime format.

I have tried Convert.ToDateTime, and all sorts of things, but it just won't work!

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the culture setting on the live server is different to that of the dev machine.

[From the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> *If provider is a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic), the current culture is used.*

So you need to specify the InvariantCulture try this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(datetimeString, "dd/MM/yyyy", 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: Yeah, but I added that and it spat it out, but I solved it another way now myself. Thanks anyhow

Comment: @Andy5 - Spat it out? What was the error? How did you solve it?